# Slow Ubuntu 16.04 boot

Tags: boot

First of all, sorry for my english.

This question has been asked numerous times here, but none of the existing answers I've seen have helped. Recently my Ubuntu started booting very slowly and I am unable to pinpoint the problem.

My computer:

HP laptop

Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4

Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)

6GB ram

Drive: 1 TB HDD (200 GB partition for Ubuntu)

Here is the critical-chain:

```
graphical.target @22.883s
└─multi-user.target @22.883s
  └─getty.target @22.883s
    └─getty@tty1.service @22.883s
      └─rc-local.service @22.875s +1ms
        └─network-online.target @22.875s
          └─network.target @19.124s
            └─wpa_supplicant.service @20.581s +210ms
              └─basic.target @16.851s
                └─sockets.target @16.851s
                  └─snapd.socket @16.825s +25ms
                    └─sysinit.target @16.800s
                      └─swap.target @16.800s
                        └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-dd0eab86\x2d0736\x2d4b29\x2d96db\x2d248bbda4b5fd.swap @16.799s
                          └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-dd0eab86\x2d0736\x2d4b29\x2d96db\x2d248bbda4b5fd.device @16.601s
```

And here is the top of systemd-analyze blame:

```
     14.133s dev-sda6.device
     12.085s ufw.service
      8.470s systemd-udevd.service
      4.863s grub-common.service
      4.803s irqbalance.service
      4.759s apport.service
      4.749s ondemand.service
      4.748s speech-dispatcher.service
      4.543s lightdm.service
      3.748s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      3.341s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      3.201s ModemManager.service
      3.124s snapd.service
      2.939s accounts-daemon.service
      2.077s tor@default.service
      1.969s NetworkManager.service
      1.657s keyboard-setup.service
      1.318s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.239s thermald.service
      1.102s systemd-journald.service
       844ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
```

Fstab and blkid show matching UUID as seen below (/dev/sda6 being the partition where Ubuntu is installed):

Fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=ab656f95-a5bc-474e-b32e-dd5fd628df0c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
# UUID=82F4-308F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=dd0eab86-0736-4b29-96db-248bbda4b5fd none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/e37e65a4-be47-4d23-ae24-f6b594e1af73 /mnt/e37e65a4-be47-4d23-ae24-f6b594e1af73 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5236F1FE36F1E341 /mnt/5236F1FE36F1E341 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
```

And blkid:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="82F4-308F" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="c9c3486b-c904-4c41-add9-fe592e5f80c7"
/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="407c2ae6-5977-4e64-885f-f3d2d17f6f82"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Windows" UUID="5236F1FE36F1E341" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="977a7aba-d73c-4a4b-ac90-eaaff77a8d48"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Windows RE tools" UUID="723A90143A8FD40F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="05b2b999-21a8-4c9e-b0ff-fbc31fb5553e"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="F89A631C9A62D722" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="7e8d4340-8605-421d-9171-1513af182d23"
/dev/sda6: UUID="ab656f95-a5bc-474e-b32e-dd5fd628df0c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="90367f00-0a2b-4953-8719-3bf793a7d6e6"
/dev/sda7: UUID="dd0eab86-0736-4b29-96db-248bbda4b5fd" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="4ed3d6b5-0a84-4d22-90c3-914c4cab03fd"
/dev/sda8: PARTUUID="88586d67-7d48-43ad-87b7-ec151c78b3a1"
/dev/sda9: UUID="e37e65a4-be47-4d23-ae24-f6b594e1af73" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="227c7963-f676-4d86-bb73-06b1a54ca4fb"
```

Any help is appreciated! If there is any futher information I can provide please tell me.

Edit:

A snippet from dmesg:

```
[    7.770069] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    7.795242] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    8.092089] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   18.504979] EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   18.527181] systemd-journald[247]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
```

Some kind of mounting problem?

Edit2:

systemd-analyze time:

```
Startup finished in 3.660s (firmware) + 3.717s (loader) + 4.267s (kernel) + 23.213s (userspace) = 34.859s
```

Comment: The provided info doesn't show anything outstanding. I'd check `less /var/log/dmesg`, and look for large timestamp gaps or errors.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! When I enter your command, empty page opens with "(Nothing has been logged yet.)"

Comment: I edited my first post and added few lines from dmesg.

Comment: Not sure why you did that. There is a 10 sec gap in dmesg, which is hardly catastrophic. I'd assume "very slow" should mean 3-4 times longer gaps. Can you add the output of `systemd-analyze --time` as well, for time reference.

Comment: Thanks again. I edited my first post. It is still a lot slower (about 10-15 secs) than it used to be.

Comment: I have a hard time believing you. It's 35 seconds all added up. Want faster boot times, get an SSD.

Comment: That would be strange since both Windows 10 and Kali Linux still boot faster than Ubuntu on my system. (I have them on the same computer)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend two things:

- fsck (file system check) your hard disk
- temporarily comment out two mounts in /etc/fstab

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

And try testing with these lines commented out in /etc/fstab...

note: Use the above method to get to the root prompt. You may have to manually remount your drive as r/w with `sudo mount -o rw,remount /` to be able to edit/save edits, and then `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/e37e65a4-be47-4d23-ae24-f6b594e1af73 /mnt/e37e65a4-be47-4d23-ae24-f6b594e1af73 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5236F1FE36F1E341 /mnt/5236F1FE36F1E341 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Fsck completed without errors. I commented those two lines and rebooted but it made no difference. Those two lines were added by Ubuntu Disks application, because I didn't want those two partitions to show up in Ubuntu toolbar.

Comment: Well, we tried a few things :-) If it's truely a 35 sec boot with a HDD, then you're doing well. You can't really compare Windows boot times, as yes, it **does** boot fast, but watch what happens after you log in... it crunches and grinds bringing up a working desktop. If you want 10 sec boot times, you'll need to get a SSD.